# Returning largest value in new column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data

```
Pet xVal
Cat 1
Cat 7
Cat 9
Dog 2
Dog 3
Dog 4
```

Is it possible to to return the highest value for each data set in an additional column? So the the data above, the expect output would be :-

```
Pet xVal Largest
Cat 1    9
Cat 7    9
Cat 9    9
Dog 2    4
Dog 3    4
Dog 4    4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using window functions:

```
select pet, xval, max(xval) over (partition by pet) as largest
from the_table;
```